# How to create a pattern for dates in Android

Tags: android, pattern-matching

For being sure that an String is only compounded of alpha characters, I create this pattern:

```
Pattern onlyLetters;
onlyLetters = Pattern.compile("[[:alpha:]- ]+");
```

Then I check if the String matches with it...

For being sure that an String is only compounded of numbers from 0 to 9, I create this pattern:

```
Pattern onlyNumbers;
onlyNumbers = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
```

Then I check if the String matches with it...

But I don't know how to do this for dates with this format: **dd/MM/YYYY**

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern will change depending on how strict you want to be about accepting input. If you know you will always have two digits for the day of the month (e.g. "08" instead of just "8") and always have four digits for the year (e.g. "1998" instead of "98"), then you can use

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}");
```